# Strategy Pattern with derived alogrithms calling methods on context

Tags: design-patterns, strategy-pattern

I am in need for some design help.
I have a class, let's call it a spaceship which can implement several behaviors.
I've defined an interface to declare the operations each behavior supports.
Until now this is the classic strategy pattern.

However, the implemented strategies need to be able to call actions and methods on the context class. I've been thinking of passing along the context as an interface itself to the encapsulated algorithms.

Is this the best approach? If not, what would you recommend?

[image]

Comment: I would say this is a good approach using Dependency Injection. That way the behavior does not need to track a context type and just needs to ensure that the action/method is available on the context class object.

Comment: Can you give more details on the Context class?  Or include it in the SpaceShip Analogy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are planning to do seems fine to me. One thing to hold into account is to not pass in too much to the method(s) of your behaviour class(es). For instance, if your spaceship has an `engine behaviour`, only pass it your `fuel tank` and `drive unit`, not the whole spaceship.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what your strategies need the context for, you could consider making it event-based using the Observer pattern as well so that your strategies not coupled to the context.

An example could be if your strategies cause something in your context to change, these could be events that some intermediary (or your context itself) subscribe to.